# Cross origin read blocking React - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to fetch data from REST API running on lh:5000

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          cat
            ? `http://localhost:5000/api/products?category=${cat}`
            : "http://localhost:5000/api/products"
        );
        console.log(res);
      } catch (err) {}
      setProducts(res.data)
    };
  }, [cat]);
```

cat is a prop.
I get 2 errors :

1. Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
2. res is not defined.

I get 1 warning getProducts is defined but never used

How do I fix these errors? Thanks

Comment: You need to show how `setProducts` is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You have not called getProducts function so its getting warning **getProducts is defined but never used**.

And secondly you are accessing variable res other than their scope access it in try.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          cat
            ? `http://localhost:5000/api/products?category=${cat}`
            : "http://localhost:5000/api/products"
        );
        console.log(res);
        setProducts(res.data) // set state here
       } catch (err) {}
    
    };
  getProducts(); // call function too.
  }, [cat]);
```